# why are my downloads using Chrome remaining incomplete?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, download

Since the last two days, any file that i try and download remains incomplete. i'm using Chrome for Windows 7. I have not changed the proxy settings in any way. All file downloads  reach 90 % completion and get stuck thereafter. please help

Comment: which downloads?

Comment: Is it just one website in particular causing you grief?  If it is, it could be something on their end.

Comment: Well, i was trying to reinstall utorrent after it crashed and that's when the problem began. I tried to install other torrent clients, the problem happened with all the softwares. The downloads began, but hung up just nearing the end. Today I tried downloading a couple of Youtube video using the Studio manager software which normally runs trouble free, but it got interrupted and i got a "Check proxy settings" message. The proxy settings seem unchanged, unless there's some deeper tech involved. I tried Internet explorer also, but the same problem persists. Thank you for your response..

Comment: So it’s not Chrome. You should edit and re-tag the question to reflect the generality of the problem (e.g., `Why do my downloads not finish?`) Does it happen with downloads of all sizes or just specific sizes? Try getting a bandwidth monitor to observe the network traffic to see if you can find clues like if it’s triggered by a specific amount of time or a specific amount of data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your Anti-Virus software scanning the downloaded file before you are allowed to open it.  If the file is very large this can take a while.

Look around in your program's options to disable it.  Every Anti-Virus program is different and yours will probably have a different name, but AVG's technology is called "Web Protection".

Reference:

- http://www.avgsecurity.co.za/faq/technical-faq/avg-85/computer-protection/internet-and-network-protection/web-shield